# Can MySQL string functions (such as "TRIM") act on a 1-column SELECT clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a complex SQL query.  My question can be simplified to the query shown here, which **gives a syntax error**:

```
SELECT 
  LENGTH 
  (SELECT 
    p.item_description 
  FROM
    ssilogic_main.`products` p 
  WHERE p.item_id = '3M.10118')
```

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT 
>       p.item_description    FROM
>       ssilogic_main.`products` p    WHERE p' at line 3

**Note that the following, similar, SQL query succeeds without error:**

```
SELECT 
  LENGTH 
  ('3M.10118')
```

**... properly returning `8`.**

The question is: Is it possible to have the MySQL string functions, such as `LENGTH` or `TRIM`, act on the 1-column result of a `SELECT` clause?

Comment: Good answer the one you got. It's clear looking at the documenation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length because it's LENGTH(str). It requires a string and SELECT something is not ever a string unless you do the trick

Comment: @MaximilianoRios By `the trick`, do you mean adding an extra set of parentheses around the `SELECT`?  ... will that cause MySQL (or SQL) to treat the single-column result of the query as a string?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to write this as:

```
SELECT LENGTH((SELECT p.item_description 
               FROM ssilogic_main.`products` p 
               WHERE p.item_id = '3M.10118'
              )
             )
```

Subqueries need to be surrounded by their own set of parentheses.  The more natural way to write it is:

```
SELECT (SELECT length(p.item_description)
        FROM ssilogic_main.`products` p 
        WHERE p.item_id = '3M.10118'
        LIMIT 1
       )
```

The `limit` ensures that, indeed, only one row is returned.

Comment: Will the second query work correctly if no row is matched? I'm pretty sure the first won't.

Comment: This worked!  I did *not* need to reorder the arguments.  I simply needed to add an extra set of parentheses around the SELECT block.

Comment: @Barmar . . . Both should return `NULL` if no row is matched.  A query that returns one row and one column is this context is called a scalar subquery.  With a scalar subquery, no rows is treated as `NULL`.

Comment: @hd1 - I still have 5 minutes to go before I am allowed to accept this answer.  I already tried.

Comment: Note that in my *real* query, a `CASE` block is used to ensure that the result of the `SELECT` is not `NULL`.